# Is there a way to keep Google Search settings when logged-in with the Google Account?

Tags: google-search, google-account

I have three computers, where I use three different browsers in each computer. I sometimes have to re-change the settings for Google search, even if I am logged-in with my Google Account.

Is there a way to get the same search settings in all the browsers where I am logged-in with my Google Account?

Answer (score 2):

Options you can set can be found on the [Google Preferences page](http://www.google.com/preferences). For more details you can use [this post](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=1224171&answer=35892) as a reference guide.

Comment: I understand the options shown in the preference page. What I would like to know is how to set them once for my Google account, and avoid setting them for each computer I have, and for each browser I use.

Comment: If you save these preferences, then while using other computer if you have logged in to your account, it does use the saved preferences. I do use multiple PCs and google synch feature is a huge savior for me.